# How to query the total count of base on there skills and attendance?

Tags: c#, sqlite

How to total the available user base on attendance that reference on their skills?

In my Sqlite database I have 2 tables:

```
TABLE: Skill Available
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Username | Skill_1| Skill_2 | Skill_3 | Skill_4 |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Mark     | 1      | 1       | 1       | 1       |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Jordan   | 1      | 0       | 1       | 0       | 
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| John     | 1      | 1       | 0       | 0       | 
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Edward   | 1      | 1       | 0       | 0       | 
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
Note: Zero represents users that doesn't have that skill. (1/0 = true/false)

TABLE: Attendance 
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Username | Site  | Shift | SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Mark     | Bldg1 | Night | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 0   | 0   |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Jordan   | Bldg1 | Night | 1   | 1   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1   |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| John     | Bldg2 | Day   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Edward   | Bldg1 | Night | 1   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
Note: Zero represents restday. (1/0 = true/false)
```

By using the two tables above how could I achieved this result in query?

```
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| SkillList | SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Skill_1   | 4   | 3   | 2   | 2   | 3   | 3   | 3   |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Skill_2   | 3   | 3   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 2   | 2   |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Skill_3   | 2   | 2   | 1   | 0   | 2   | 1   | 1   |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Skill_4   | 1   | 1   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0   | 0   |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: What are the numbers in attendance table?  Are they bit flags (attended true/false) ?  If so, there is no relationship between the two tables.

Comment: yeah there were boolean

Comment: What is the logic of deriving the result?

Answer (score 1):

This I tested will yield the result you're looking for. might not be the most elegant and performant way to do it but i just did this in a hurry.
hope will be helpful anyway :)

```
select 
    'Skill_1',
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.SUN = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_1 = 1) > 0) SUN,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.MON = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_1 = 1) > 0) MON,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.TUE = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_1 = 1) > 0) TUE,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.WED = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_1 = 1) > 0) WED,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.THU = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_1 = 1) > 0) THU,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.FRI = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_1 = 1) > 0) FRI,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.SAT = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_1 = 1) > 0) SAT
union 

select
    'Skill_2',
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.SUN = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_2 = 1) > 0) SUN,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.MON = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_2 = 1) > 0) MON,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.TUE = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_2 = 1) > 0) TUE,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.WED = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_2 = 1) > 0) WED,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.THU = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_2 = 1) > 0) THU,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.FRI = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_2 = 1) > 0) FRI,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.SAT = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_2 = 1) > 0) SAT

union 

select
    'Skill_3',
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.SUN = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_3 = 1) > 0) SUN,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.MON = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_3 = 1) > 0) MON,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.TUE = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_3 = 1) > 0) TUE,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.WED = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_3 = 1) > 0) WED,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.THU = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_3 = 1) > 0) THU,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.FRI = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_3 = 1) > 0) FRI,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.SAT = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_3 = 1) > 0) SAT

union 

select
    'Skill_4',
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.SUN = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_4 = 1) > 0) SUN,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.MON = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_4 = 1) > 0) MON,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.TUE = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_4 = 1) > 0) TUE,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.WED = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_4 = 1) > 0) WED,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.THU = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_4 = 1) > 0) THU,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.FRI = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_4 = 1) > 0) FRI,
    (Select COUNT(*) from Attendance att where att.SAT = 1 and 
        (select COUNT(*) from SkillsAvailable where Username = att.Username and Skill_4 = 1) > 0) SAT
```

ps. this is done on sql server db, so you might see some syntax descrepencies. Highly unlikely but if you did just use the sqlite counterpart.

ps2. in sql server you can achieve this using PIVOT and window functions but you might be able to do similar stuff using sqlite built in functionality to avoid the repetition in the scripts.